How to change an iterative linear interpolation into a formula?
I'm programming a game which needs to perform a simple linear interpolation in an iterative manner on every frame the game draws the screen. See the below example:
x[1] = c*(b - x[0]) + x[0]
...
...
x[n+1] = c*(b - x[n]) + x[n]

b and c are constants.
x[0] is selected by hand and the rest of the x's ("x[n]") are calculated from that each frame.
I want to change the algorithm into a formula which would allow me to calculate directly what the x[n] would be. I also want the "n" to be a floating point value, allowing me to find the exact results anywhere between the frames.
How do I do that?

I would look up the phrase "exponential decay". And also, just today, I happened across this youtube video, and it goes through your exact problem in quite some detail, specifically from the point of game programming (which includes a dive into framerate issues).

This is an excellent video describing exactly the situations you're looking at. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSNQuFEDOyQ

@CyclotomicField & Arthur: Those seem to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

The comments to the question gave the correct answer: exponential decay is what easily solves this issue. The frame by frame linear interpolation using the previous frames output value follows the curve of exponential decay.
To use the exponential decay to replace the frame by frame iterative linear interpolation calulations, we can do the following:

Calculate the delta of the two values we want to interpolate
between.
Multiply that delta value with exponential decay amount,
based on how much time in seconds we moved forward.
The resulting value directly tells us how far away we are now from
the target value.

Here's some example code which can be run frame by frame:
decay         = pow(decay_speed, -delta_time_in_seconds)
delta         = target_value - current_value
current_value = target_value - decay*delta

decay_speed is an arbitrary constant which controls how fast we reach the target value.
decay_speed must be larger than 1 for this to work.
(I hope my code above doesn't have bugs in it, as I didn't try compiling and running it.)
